# Can I add my add-in into "analyze" section of Visual Studio menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsct

Visual Studio main window top menu contains "Analyze" item that upon expansion shows items such as "profiler", "run code analysis", etc. If I want to add my add-in command invokation into any Visual Studio menu I need to craft a [command table (.vsct file)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166366.aspx) and declare that my command belongs to a specific section   by specifying its id.

The problem is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only lists menu IDs for sections other than "analyze" - "analyze" section is never mentioned.

Is adding my add-in to "analyze" section allowed?

Comment: You can use the VSCT PowerToy extension to figure out the menu-id(s) you need: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSCTPowerToy

Answer (score 3):

You'll need this in the `<Symbols>` portion of your .vsct:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidDiagMenuGroup" value="{CD68F8E6-2842-4F7E-AF7B-5A019631CEB5}">
  <IDSymbol name="IDM_DIAG_TOPLEVELMENU" value="0x0001"/>
</GuidSymbol>
```

Then your parent for your group should be:

```
<Parent guid="guidDiagMenuGroup" id="IDM_DIAG_TOPLEVELMENU"/>
```

Comment: I'm very late to the party but I'm struggling with the same problem. Unfortunately, the answer doesn't work on VS 2017 update 9.3